# Probability of event independent of random variables

Tags: probability, independence

Let {$X_n$} be a sequence of independent random variables and for each $n$, the event $A$ is independent of $X_1$, $X_2$,..., $X_n$. Show that $P(A)$ is $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Please edit your post and add your attempts at solving this problem. Take the chance to also take [tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), see some [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and how to [ask a good question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sounds like a messed-up statement of a Kolmogorov $0$-$1$ law.

Answer (score 1):

**That conjecture is false:**  Define the sequence $X_0,X_1,X_2,..., \sim \text{IID Bern}(\theta)$ with some parameter $0<\theta<1$, and let $A \equiv \mathbb{I}(X_0=1)$.  This meets your antecedent condition, but contradicts the result to be proved.

Comment: What is $Bern$? Bernoulli RV? Is this shorthand convention stated/published somewhere for me to lookup in the future?